# Ajax request delimiters for data to be sent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have such an issue

```
var url = "index.php?id=123&sid=321";
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&url="+url,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
```

Now here we have url which contains an & , but & is used to delimit data variables to be sent to server and so since we have this sign in url it thinks that this is a delimiter, and I am not getting the full url variable.

Can somebody help with a wise solution.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an object instead of string for the `data` field:

```
var url = "index.php?id=123&sid=321";
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", url: url },
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
});
```

Comment: and in php to make json_decode right?, otherwise how it will understand that this is an object?

Comment: No, you don't need to do json_decode. jQuery will pass these fields as POST fields, and your PHP script will be able to read them separately, the same way as you usually read data from form posts - $_POST["name"] and $_POST["url"]

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'index.php?id=123&sid=321';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    name: 'John',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```

It would be better to pack all data with JSON as above, and build the URL server-side as part of whatever script you have handling this AJAX request.

Comment: var url here is just an example , i need it to be sent to server, it can be something else for example var url = firstname&lastname.

Comment: Fyodor Soikin's answer is the best way to deal with this situation

Answer (score 1):

Put your data in a JSON.

```
data: {id: '123', sid: '321'}
```